# CakePhp save changes only in middle table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Here is the problem what I have

I have 3 tables m:n

```
Users -> addresses_users -> Addresses
```

During adding new user I am selecting from dropdown X Addresses and after I click save I have to save new user data (new user in Users table), make mapping in addresses_user table and Addresses table shouldnt be changed, cos I have already those addresses in DB.

So, if i use code like this

input in ctp with
name="addresses[]"

In controller

```
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->
    if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
      $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
      return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view/' . $user->id]);
    } else {
      $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
  }
```

Cakephph makes mapping automatically and want to save new user, mapping and information about addresses.

Is there way to make this automatically with cakephp that he saves new user and make mapping or I should use another input name (that cakephp doesnt make patch with addresses) and after save make foreach with all addresses_id and save values direct to addresses_users table?

Or there is better ideas?